# PHP - How to get JSON in another javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have HTML source file that,

```
// target.html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
<script src="../../Common/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
<script src="../../Common/js/select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var JsonData = [{"one":[{"ID":4179,"Name":"Jack"},{"ID":4180,"Name":"Jill"}]}];
...
```

It contains a JSON, so called 'JsonData'.
And what I want is getting and printing 'JsonData' in a PHP.
I make the PHP like this,

```
// test.php
include ("./target.html");
readfile ("./target.html");

$html = file_get_html("/Users/Desktop/target.html");
// a new dom object
$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
// load the html into the object ***/
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$target= $dom->getElementsByTagName("script"); // here u use your desired tag    
print_r($target);
```

But I can't see the JSON data in this way.
Could you please help me.

Comment: Whatever you're doing, you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: Why don't you store json data in a .json file and read the date from it??

Comment: I want to get json file directly, but I can't. Because I don't have right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**file_get_html** function does not exist with my PHP so I just used the **file_get_contents** instead which is included built-in with PHP. I also replaced your **print_r** with what is needed to get your problem solved. You have 3 script tags in your HTML file so I accessed it using an index which is **2**. Indexes starts with 0.

```
// test.php
include ("./target.html");
readfile ("./target.html");

$html = file_get_contents("/Users/Desktop/target.html"); //replaced file_get_html
// a new dom object
$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
// load the html into the object ***/
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$target= $dom->getElementsByTagName("script"); // here u use your desired tag    

echo $target->item(2)->nodeValue; //replaced print_r
```